# React JS: Does my Application work correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have made a simple to-do application link http://todo-app.myartsonline.com/

For Navigation I used react-router-dom library

It works great but my doubt is when we go to Application and click **Instruction** It works great, Now try this link http://todo-app.myartsonline.com/Instruction
this will lead to error, 
Obviously, an error occurs because Application hasn't load yet!

Is it Issue/problem if yes how to solve it.
How Can I display directly

My React Navigation Code

```
    import { Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
    import history from './history.js';

    <Router history={history}>

    <Container fluid>

        <NavbarComponent />

          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Streams/list" exact component={StreamList} />
          <Route path="/Streams/new" exact component={StreamCreate} />
          <Route path="/Streams/edit" exact component={StreamEdit} />
          <Route path="/Streams/delete" exact component={StreamDelete} />
          <Route path="/Streams/show/:id" exact component={StreamShow} />
          <Route path="/Instruction" exact component={Instruction} />
          <Route path="/AboutProj" exact component={AboutProj} />
    </Container>

  </Router>
```

Here is my History.js

```
    var createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory;
     export default createHistory();
```

Comment: You need to configure your server to rewrite your requests to index.html. This is an important config required for Single page application. Where are you hosting your application currently ?

Comment: I am hosting at https://www.awardspace.com/ subdomain hosting
I have just build project using react build command and upload build files,
what should I do in this case, thank you in advance :D

Comment: I have no experience in awardspace.com. You could try Firebase hosting from google its free and you just have to select SPA(Single Page Application) during the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using `browserHistory`.

When you go to this link `http://todo-app.myartsonline.com/Instruction`, your server doesn't return index.html so react router doesn't come into play.
But when you go to `http://todo-app.myartsonline.com/` and then route to `instruction`, this is client side routing, server is not aware of this route.

For browser history to work correctly you need to have server side configuration. For all request send index.html in the response. This should be the last one in order of requests.

1) Configuring Express:-

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

2) Configuring WebpackDevServer

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for responding sir, I must edit the question I haven't used browserHistory Router and I 'm using JSON server at backend but that stuff doesn't come into play at this movement

Comment: history object you are using will be using some type of history I was assuming this is browserHistory.

Comment: Did this to achieve wild-card navigation sorry told wrong info Used BrowserHistory,
coded this long time ago

Comment: You need to create .htaccess file in UI project, use rewrite module to reroute all calls to index.html